# How to checkout to a particular commit in smartgit

Tags: git, smartgit

I would like to checkout a specific commit in the SmartGit. How do I do that? Is it possible to do something like checking out a certain revision in SVN?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, checking out a certain commit is similar to checking out a certain SVN revision.

The preferred way will be to open the *Log window*, locate the desired commit, invoke **Branch|Check Out** and select the commit there.

Alternatively, you can do that from the *Working Tree window*: make sure your focus is in the **Directories**-view, select **Branch|Check Out** and select the commit there.